# Change event triggering too early on select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-select, eventtrigger

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

**The HTML:**

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$('#mySelect').change( function() {
    // do stuff
} );
```

The problem is that when I move my mouse cursor over the options, `do stuff` happens as I hover over one of the options, before I actually select the new option. How do I avoid this behaviour so that `.change()` is triggered only when I have finished choosing a new option in the select?

**Edit 1: Further information**

Apparently this code would not cause behaviour described. In the actual code the select boxes are being updated as further data is loaded via `.get()` and processed.

**Edit 2: Actual function that updates a select box**

This function is the one in my code that updates one of the select boxes after more data has loaded. The global variable `padm_courses` is an array of course objects, that have a `code` and `name` property used to populate the course filter select box.

```
function loadCourseFilter() {
    var selected = '';
    var sel = $('<select>').attr('id','padmCourseFilter');
    $(padm_courses).each(function() {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.code).text(this.name));
    });
    if($('#padmCourseFilter').length) {
        selected = $('#padmCourseFilter').val();
        $('#padmCourseFilter').replaceWith(sel);
        if(selected != '') $('#padmCourseFilter option[value="'+escape(selected)+'"]').prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        sel.appendTo('#padm_hub_filters');
    }

    $('#padmCourseFilter').change( function() {
        processMCRsByCourse($('#padmCourseFilter').val());
        var tables = $('.sv-datatable').DataTable();
        tables.rows('.duplicate').remove().draw();
        filterTheBlockFilter();
    } );
}
```

Comment: Either use `$("#\\#mySelect")` or `id="mySelect"`

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo in my question example code, not my actual code. I have editted it and fixed.

Comment: `do stuff happens as I hover over one of the options` Nothing in the code you've shown would cause that behaviour. Could you show a more complete sample of the problem

Comment: change() does not trigger that behaviour. The issue must be somewhere else in your code. Are you using mouseenter, mouseleave or something like this anywhere?

Comment: Hmm, the select boxes are being updated as `ajax` loads more options. Could that trigger the change of value to the current hover state?

Comment: no, but it could trigger a change, if the value is changed... Hard to tell without having the code I guess.

Comment: Okay, I've added the code that updates the select box after the ajax call. I've got a feeling I need to do something a bit cleverer than merely replacing the old select box with a new one with updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. It seems that when triggered, the function `loadCourseFilter` was recreating the selectbox from scratch each time and overwriting the old one. This caused weird behaviour when hovering over one of the options.

A revised version of the function adds only new options, and does not update the filter if nothing was actually added...

```
function loadCourseFilter() {
    var sel, output;
    if($('#padmCourseFilter').length) {
        var count = 0;
        sel = $('padmCourseFilter');
        output = [];

        $(padm_courses).each(function() {
            if($('#padmCourseFilter option[value="'+this.code+'"]').length == 0) {
                count++;
                output.push('<option value="'+this.code+'">'+this.name+'</option>');
            }
        });
        if(count > 0) {
            sel.append(output.join(''));
            sortDropDownListByText('padmCourseFilter');
        }
    } else {
        sel = $('<select>').attr('id','padmCourseFilter');
        $(padm_courses).each(function() {
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.code).text(this.name));
        });
        sel.appendTo('#padm_hub_filters');
    }

    $('#padmCourseFilter').change( function() {
        processMCRsByCourse($('#padmCourseFilter').val());
        var tables = $('.sv-datatable').DataTable();
        tables.rows('.duplicate').remove().draw();
        filterTheBlockFilter();
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your change event

```
$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```